# insert category based on row uniqueness in excel

Tags: excel, row

I have a spreadsheet with rows as follows:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | a | c |
| c | c | c |

if a occurs twice then the score should be pass
if b occurs twice then the score should be fail
if all values are unique, the score should be retake

| c1 | c2 | c3 | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | retake |
| a | a | b | pass |
| c | b | b | fail |

I can get pass and fail e.g.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"a")>=2,"pass",IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"b")=2,"split",IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"c")=2,"fail")))`

I need to incorporate a remapping of the unique count to a string - I have this which prints the number of unique values but i cant include a text replacement
`=IF((COUNTA(UNIQUE(a1:c1), 3)), "retake")`

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your expected results don't seem to match your description?

Comment: Something seems to be missing in the latter part of your formula (`...IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"c")=2,"fail")`), This may solve your problem: `=IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"a")>=2,"pass",IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"b")>=2,"split",IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"c")=2,"fail","retake")))`

Comment: BigBen ah thanks for pointing that out. I have amended it .Thanks @cybernetic.nomad. That does work thank you. the only thing then is it applies the retake to the entire column in the event that the rows for columns c1, c2 and c3 are empty. i trid to combine the COUNTIF with COUNTIFS to sum unique values to avoid it but couldn't combine the commands properly

Comment: Wrap it in `IF(COUNTA(A2:C2)=0,"",<formula>)`